# Mysql error and I can't perform bundle install

Tags: mysql, ruby

```
Could not find mysql2-0.5.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

```
bundle install
/usr/bin/env: “ruby3.0”: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
```

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.7.6p219 (2022-04-12 revision c9c2245c0a) [x86_64-linux]
```

```
> which ruby  
/snap/bin/ruby

> which bundler  
/usr/local/bin/bundler

> gem env   
cannot snap-exec: cannot exec "/snap/ruby/272/bin/gem": no such file or directory
```

Comment: Does your Gemfile have a line that says `ruby "3.0.X"`? If so change that to 2.7.6 or install a compatible ruby version.

Comment: Ruby version installed via snap 2.7.6, I uninstalled this ruby ​​from version 3.0

Comment: I have no idea what that means. The error you posted is that bundler is looking for this to be ruby 3 and your ruby version shown is 2.7.6. That is all I know and thus my recommendations.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the output of the following commands: `which ruby`, `which bundler`, `gem env`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a problem installing the ruby ​​packages, I couldn't install it through rvm, so I used snap. I updated the post with the requested information.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Please add the output of `head -1 /snap/ruby/272/bin/gem`, and `ls -l /snap/bin/b*`, and `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Your Ruby installation seems quite messed up. I would delete all and any current Ruby installations completely, and install with RVM instead. That is the easiest solution. Helping you here through StackOverflow is going to be extremely slow. It could take several days to figure out your problem. SO is not really a fast interactive help system, so it is not suited that well for your type of problem solving.

Comment: I concur! I ran into a bunch of Ruby install issues when I was first getting started. Totally up to you, but I was a big fan of [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) instead of `rvm`, though I now use [`asdf`](https://asdf-vm.com/) for almost all my version management (and have so far loved it). Good luck!